# Create the minimum number of sets to cover all data

Tags: java, algorithm, set

I have a problem to create a minimum number of sets to cover the whole data set.

The problem has a data domain and a few exclusivity constraints. The exclusivity constraint states which data should not be in the same set.

The goal is to find minimum number of sets. The number of the sets doesn't have to be as balanced as possible (but would be nice to have).

Example 1:

```
Domain = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
Exclusivity = 1!=2, 3!=4, 4!=5, 5!=6,

Answer is two sets: {1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}
```

Example 2:

```
Domain = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
Exclusivity = 1!=2, 2!=3, 3!=4, 4!=5

anwser is two sets: {1, 3, 5, 6}, {2, 4}
```

Example 3:

```
Domain = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Exclusivity = 1!=2, 2!=3, 3!=4, 4!=5, 5!=1

answer is three sets : {1, 3}, {2, 4}, {5}
```

Example 4:

```
Domain = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Exclusivity = 1!=2!=3!=4, 4!=5,

answer is four sets : {1, 5}, {2}, {3}, {4}
```

The != here is transitive.

Does anyone know such an algorithm to solve this problem efficiently. I couldn't remember any algorithm I leard from school that solves this problem, but that was more than 10 years ago.

Help is appreciated.

JT

Comment: Have you tried anything?  do you have an algorithm attempt that doesn't work?

Comment: Is your dataset (the `Domain` set in your examples) composed of unique numbers?

Comment: I don't think "transitive" is exactly what you mean in the last sample, because if `!=` were transitive and `1!=2` *and* `4!=5` then `1!=5` would follow from that and you'd need 5 sets.

Comment: agree. It's only transitive within one constraint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ignoring balance, this is [graph coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring).

domain <=> vertices of the graph

set <=> all vertices with a particular color

exclusivity constraints <=> edges of the graph.

Unfortunately, graph coloring is NP-hard, and the provable approximation ratios are not good. There are many, many heuristics.

Comment: I will take a look at the graph coloring, and get back to you. thanks

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view I think you could create a weighted graph. For nodes that exclude each other set weight of verticies to `Int.MAX`, for others to `0`.

Then you could try to reduce this graph for nodes that have zero routes to each-other. (I'm sure there exist some algorithm for this problem).

HTH

Comment: At the first glance, I am not sure this will work. I will think about it more.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, describing this problem as a covering problem is a bit misleading. It's actually a set partitioning problem with constraints on the partitions.

#### Solution 1

Formulate and solve it as an integer linear program (ILP). Google revealed the [Java ILP](http://javailp.sourceforge.net/). If you're interested, I can post more info on how to formulate your problem as an ILP.

#### Solution 2

Let each element in your dataset (the `Domain` set) represent a node in an undirected graph. Start with a complete graph (i.e. all the nodes are connected to each other) and drop edges based on your exclusivity constraints (i.e. if you are using an adjacency matrix `A` to represent your graph, `1!=2` implies `A(1,2) = 0` and `A(2,1) = 0`).

Then find the [minimum clique partition](http://www.csc.kth.se/~viggo/wwwcompendium/node25.html) which is equivalent [minimum graph coloring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734585/create-the-minimum-number-of-sets-to-cover-all-data/6735132#6735132).

You could however [list all maximal cliques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Listing_all_maximal_cliques) and work from there.

Comment: I guess the main question here is how to connect the nodes if we start with a graph with no path at all. I could come up with a solution, but I cannot guarantee I find the mininum number of connected components.

Comment: I don't see how this works. Consider a domain `{1, 2, 3}` and exclusivity constraint `1!=2`. Doesn't this method produce a graph with edges `(1, 3)` and `(2, 3)`, with just one component?

Comment: @Michael J Barber: In my haste, I jumped for an easy solution. It is in fact the minimum clique partitioning problem.